# Using on_sent_ok multiple times in Wordpress Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms

The Contact Form 7 plugin for Wordpress allows additional settings to be included. I currently use `on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit');"` to track goal conversions in GA (Google Analytics) which works very well, however I need to also add Facebook Pixel conversion tracking to this, the issue is when adding in `on_sent_ok: “fbq(‘track’, ‘Lead’);”` the form then does not return the sent message and clear the form, it does still send. I have tried moving the 'submit' to trigger the message to the end but it still does not work.

Is there anyway I can write a a function that will allow me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them to the same event:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit'); fbq('track', 'Lead');"
```

Also, watch out for curly quotes...